# Initializing size of hash table

Tags: initialization, size, hashtable, load-factor

If I have a hash table that I know will store 13 items, how can I initialize my table to an appropriate size? I read in my book that the load factor should be at or below 2/3. Does this mean that if I already know that the maximum number of items in my table at any point will be 13, I could do something like:

```
tableSize = nextPrime((numEntries * 3)/2);
```

My thinking with the above assignment is that numEntries represents the number 13 and since I know the load factor has to be under 2/3, I find what value I need to make the ratio 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a hashtable as `new Hashtable(initialSize, loadFactor)`

In simple terms the load factor determines when to allocate more memory to the hashtable

You must be aware that you need not specify memory at initialization to a hashtable unlike arrays. An appropriate loadfactor helps to reduce the overhead of repeated memory allocation.

AFAIK a load factor of 2/3 indicates that the hashtable be allocated with memory when it is 2/3rds full.

Check out : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

If you know that the hashtable will be storing 13 entries why not initialize it with

`new Hashtable(13)` and not worry about the **loadfactor** which comes into picture when new allocation is needed.